# What does "bogambo" mean when Kramer says to George "Hey Bogambo they've been in the neighborhood for 48 years"?

Tags: seinfeld

What does "bogambo" mean when Kramer says to George "Hey Bogambo they've been in the neighborhood for 48 years" in the Seinfeld episode "The Mom and Pop Store"? What is the reference here? The only thing I could find on Google is a similar word "mogambo", but I don't see why that would be funny or make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Reviewing [the script](https://subslikescript.com/series/Seinfeld-98904/season-6/episode-8-The_Mom_and_Pop_Store):

> Hey, Bucambo...
>
> they've been in the neighborhood
> for 48 years.

Googling for "Bucambo" it might be considered to be a [running gag](https://seinfeld.fandom.com/wiki/Running_Gags_in_Seinfeld) that Kramer uses nonsense [nicknames](https://www.reddit.com/r/seinfeld/comments/hktyoq/kramer_and_jerry_nicknames/) for people:

> Kramer uses strange nicknames for George, such as 'mojambo', which he comes up with on the spot.

Here an example of`mojambo` used as a [nickname for Newman](https://youtu.be/U4mY01UksQU?t=117) (1:57 time)